# how to write multiple value of css property in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const myStyle = {
    animation: 'fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 3s'
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='app' style={myStyle}>
       </div>}
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

How can I write multiple css property value into react? A CSS property animation have two value i.e fadein and fadeout. with fadeout one extra value 3s.

Comment: that's still one property `animation`. Are you sure that's the problem you are facing? why do you have a closing `}` after `</div>`?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this work, you will need to add keyframes specifying the behaviour of fadein and fadeout for example :

```css
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define keyframes.
It is not supported by React for you to define keyframes inside the inline style object. Rather, your keyframes must be defined in a different CSS file, which your React component must then reference.

```
/* styles.css */
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[A working example you can see on my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/beautiful-franklin-rx2cll?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A23%2C1)

Answer (score -1):

Each animation is separated by a comma. The first animation is 'fadein' with a duration of 0.5 seconds. The second animation is 'fadeout' with a duration of 0.5 seconds and a delay of 3 seconds (3s).

I have made some changes to this code:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const myStyle = {
    animation: 'fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 3s'
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='app' style={myStyle}>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```